# javascript string chars replacment

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I was solving one of the w3resource js problems, which is the following:

Write a JavaScript program to rotate the string 'w3resource' in right direction by periodically removing one letter from the end of the string and attaching it to the front.

I've solved it in th following way:
HTML:

```
<div id="target0" style="margin: 50px auto; text-align: center;">w3resource</div>
<div id="target1" style="margin: 50px auto; text-align: center;">w3resource</div>
```

JS:

```
var solution = (function(){

  function htmlToArr(targetId) {
    targetId = document.getElementById(targetId);
    let targetContents = targetId.innerHTML;
    let letters = targetContents.split("");

    return letters;
  }

  function arrFirstToLast(arr) {
    first = arr.splice(0, 1);
    arr.splice(arr.length, 0, first[0]);
  }

  function arrLastToFirst(arr) {
    let last = arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1);
    arr.splice(0, 0, last[0]);
  }

  function setHtml(targetId, html) {
    targetId = document.getElementById(targetId);
    targetId.innerHTML = html;
  }

  function rotateString(targetId, direction = "left") {
    letters = htmlToArr(targetId);
    setInterval(function() {
      if (direction === "left") {
        arrFirstToLast(letters);
      } else if (direction === "right") {
        arrLastToFirst(letters);
      }
      let str = letters.join("");
      setHtml(targetId, str)
    }, 1500)
  }

  return {
    rotateString: rotateString
  }
})();
```

I've implemented an option to rotate string in one direction or another.
When I have one target string, it works fine:

```
/*case 0 - one target, works good in both directions*/
solution.rotateString("target0", "right");
```

When I have two target strings, it still works, but the second one is one-letter delayed to the first one:

```
/* case 1 - two targets, same direction, works, non-synced letters */
solution.rotateString("target0");
solution.rotateString("target1");
```

When I have two target strings and I want to rotate them in different directions, it just moves one letter in the first target and stops:

```
/* case 2 - two targets, different direction, doesen't work */
solution.rotateString("target0", "left");
solution.rotateString("target1", "right");
```

I can fix my case 2 just by implementing two different functions for two directions. But I want to understand, why is it failing, and what's my mistake in this `setInterval` if-statment implementation.

Also, I have no idea how to sync letters movement in the case 1.

Here's the pen:
https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/zPqVgg?editors=1010

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a global `letters` variable.

```
letters = htmlToArr(targetId);
```

should be a local variable:

```
var letters = htmlToArr(targetId);
```